# Mostrar datos que tengo un dropdownlist a un textArea

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un dropdownlist donde tengo datos de una tabla lo cual quiero que al seleccionar una opcion me muestre en un textArea la información. Lo estoy haciendo con razor y ya le he buscado y no se como ya... espero me puedan ayudar.

aqui tengo el codigo del dropdownlist

```
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.DropDownList("ComentarioPlantilla", (SelectList)ViewBag.ComentarioPlantilla, "Seleccione plantilla", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

donde lo tengo conectado a una BD mediante un viewBag que tengo en el controlador.

```
ViewBag.ComentarioPlantilla = new SelectList(db.Plantillas, "PlantillaId", "Comentario");
```

Y tengo este codigo pero me muestra el texto del dropdownlist al seleccionar una opcion

```
$('#ComentarioPlantilla').on('change', function () {

        if (this.value == 0) {
            $('#Comentario').val("");
        }
        else {
            $('#Comentario').val($('#ComentarioPlantilla').text());
        }

    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Opinión con respecto a la pregunta eliminada anteriormente: Considera en incluir la solución cuando la tengas, de esta forma serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo problema. Saludos.

Comment: Lo siento,  lo olvide... en cambio en esta pregunta ya pude "arreglarlo", solo le quite el texto "Seleccione plantilla" al DropDownList, para que no se viera nada más

Comment: Nada qué disculpar estimado Luis, no pasa nada, todo fresh, solo es una sugerencia y ya :D Cada quien es libre de elegir las opciones. Si has encontrado la solución para tu pregunta, en la parte inferior hay una zona donde dice "Tu Respuesta", incluye todos los datos necesarios ahí. Luego le das click en el check del costado para aceptar la respuesta, esto sirve para mantener la buena salud del sitio (efecto de % de respuestas resueltas). Saludos.